# Monitoring Turbo Boost / SpeedStep on 13" MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, turbo-boost, sandy-bridge

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" and I'm supposed to be able to turbo boost up to 2.9GHz until the processor begins to overheat. Does anyone know of a utility that can monitor the current processor speed, as opposed to the "2.3GHz" that About This Mac shows?

Comment: Bear in mind turbo boost kicks in only at very specific circumstances

Comment: What kind of circumstances will cause a turbo boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intel Power Gadget](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20) allows one to monitor the variable clock rate of the CPU on Apple Macbooks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it and it doesn't look like a very professional site, but several forums referred to this site with a program called "[CPU-x](http://netkas.org/?p=72)", which shows the frequency of the CPU. Using this should let you keep an eye on the processor speed.

Comment: CPU-Z, it's parent on Windows, can do that. I'm looking at CPU-X on my machine right now and it's just showing 25MHz x 92.5 = 2300MHz. Static view, apparently. :(

Comment: Yeah, I found it while looking for an alternative to CPUz for Mac. It claims it's dynamic, but I guess that's incorrect.